# ASP.NET disable "C:\fakepath" in FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

ASP.NET 4.0

I've checked that using both  or  control (which is a wrap of html file input) will display `"C:\fakepath\MyFile"` in both Google Chrome 12.0 and IE8.0 on my Windows 7. It only displays `"MyFile"` in FF3.6. I am trying to not display "C:\fakepath\" string since it's not usual to most users.

I already enabled displaying full path in IE security setting which mentioned in another SO thread, so that shouldn't be just an IE security issue. Not to mention GC is showing fakepath too.

I am more suspecting it's because of my compilation environment -- Windows 7 + VS2010 SP1 + MVC3 installed. Can the community tell me how to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be disabled, it's a browser security feature.  It ensures the server doesn't have access to any file information on the client.  Some browsers handle it differently, which is why in FF you just see the file name.

See this related question:

[Javascript loading clients local media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861414/javascript-loading-clients-local-media)

Comment: the html file input in my project has this fakepath behavior. But if it's not in a newly created ASP.NET 4.0 project. Why is it different? Please advise.

Comment: @Stan It doesn't matter what server side technology you are using, this is a client side problem and unfortunately there is nothing you can do about it as it is now a normal security feature for browsers.

Comment: But I compiled both projects on same PC and use same browser to test. How come one has the security feature while the other is not?

Comment: @Stan it might be due to you running the site on localhost